# iOS 7 UITableView Not Responsive

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement a UITableView. My issue is that tableview cells, in order to be selected in simulator, require the user to press and hold that cell. I don't understand why this is happening. I would like cell's to be selected with a simple tap. Here is my code. There isn't much.

## The header file:

```
#import "BasisViewController.h"

#define kDISCUSSIONS 5

@interface MyDiscussionsViewController : BasisViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myDiscussionsTable;

@end
```

## The implementation file:

```
#import "MyDiscussionsViewController.h"

@interface MyDiscussionsViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyDiscussionsViewController
@synthesize myDiscussionsTable;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Annoyingly, iOS 7 makes it so the seperators of table views are offset slightly. Get rid of this property.
    if ([myDiscussionsTable respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
        [myDiscussionsTable setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return kDISCUSSIONS;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"TheDiscussions";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    [cell.textLabel setText:@"This Discussion"];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"User selected discussion at index: %d",indexPath.row);
}

@end
```

Comment: have you used any gesture in this class?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Is there a convenient way to check?

Comment: I have created many UITableViews and I never had to press and hold for a cell to select. Perhaps there is something wrong with your Xcode simulator. Did you try it on actual device? iPad/iphone?

Comment: Easier said than done since I unfortunately don't have an iOS of my own to test on. :(

Comment: Simulator is ok but you always want to test this on a real device. I don't know how many times I had my code work perfectly on simulator just to break on actual device.

Comment: It may be gesture added on tableview.for checking gesture use this and then remove it .

     for(UIGestureRecognizer *recogniser in     myTable.gestureRecognizers)
    {
        [myTable removeGestureRecognizer:recogniser];
    }


If you want single tap then you can simply add a uibutton on tablecell and call it.

Hope that helps